# WinForms. Threading and recursion

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

So, i have a longest path search function that recursively traverses through some graph. This function must stop on **await** until the "Next" button in form is clicked. But i cannot understand how to prevent function from going back to previous calls of itself after **await**:

```
        public async void LongestPath(T current, T from, T to, Stack<Graph<T, W>.Edge> path, W summary)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(current, to)) //if arrived at the end node
            {
                if (Comparer<W>.Default.Compare(summary, longest) > 0) //if this path is the biggest
                {
                    LongestExists = true;
                    longest = summary;
                    longestPath.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
                        longestPath.Push(path.ElementAt(i));
                }
                return;
            }
            List<Pair<T, Graph<T, W>.Edge>> available = new List<Pair<T, Graph<T, W>.Edge>>(); //current vertice's available routes
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Edges.Count; i++)
            {
                Pair<T, Graph<T, W>.Edge> toAdd = new Pair<T, Graph<T, W>.Edge>();
                if (!this.Edges[i].visited)
                {
                    if (this.Edges[i].undirected)
                    {
                        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(this.Edges[i].Left, current) && !nodeVisited(this.Edges[i].Left))
                        {
                            toAdd.First = this.Edges[i].Right;
                            toAdd.Second = this.Edges[i];
                            available.Add(toAdd);
                        }
                        else if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(this.Edges[i].Right, current) && !nodeVisited(this.Edges[i].Right))
                        {
                            toAdd.First = this.Edges[i].Left;
                            toAdd.Second = this.Edges[i];
                            available.Add(toAdd);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(this.Edges[i].Left, current) && !nodeVisited(this.Edges[i].Left))
                    {
                        toAdd.First = this.Edges[i].Right;
                        toAdd.Second = this.Edges[i];
                        available.Add(toAdd);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < available.Count; i++)
            {
                available.ElementAt(i).Second.visited = true;
                path.Push(available.ElementAt(i).Second);
                visitNode(current, true); //function that just sets the "visited" flag of a vertice to true
                Task check = new Task(() => Form1.CheckNextButtonAsync()); //this task checks the state of "Next" button
                check.Start();
                await check; //the problem
                Form1.NextButtonClicked = false; //function continues from here after the button is clicked but at that moment it had already went back to previous calls of itself
                Console.Beep();
                LongestPath(available.ElementAt(i).First, from, to, path, GenericSum<W>(summary, available.ElementAt(i).Second.weight));
                visitNode(current, false);
                available.ElementAt(i).Second.visited = false;
                path.Pop();
            }
            return;
        }
```

It is pretty obvious that non-recursive function will work perfectly. But is there any way of "freeze" the thread and keep the form working so that the button could be pressed at the same time?

Comment: It is wise to [avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, none of the used methods return Task or Task<T>. So if I got the idea right it is not wise in avoiding async void

Comment: *Void-returning async methods have a specific purpose: to make asynchronous event handlers possible.* (quote from the link I posted earlier). It is Microsoft that advises you to avoid async void, not me. If you are dealing with an asynchronous event handler then async void is OK. Otherwise it's not.